# Semantic UI React item image as link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I am using *Item* (Semantic UI React) and I would like to set the image as a link. But how do I reference the link URL?

```
<Item>
    <Item.Image src={this.props.fileUrl} size='tiny' as='a' />
    <Item.Content>
    </Item.Content>
</Item>
```

If I wrap `Item.Image` in a `a`-container, the padding gets messed up...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on right way, you need to use the SUIR's augmentation, all non `Item.Image` props will be by-passed:

```
<Item.Image
  as='a'
  href='http://example.com'
  src={this.props.fileUrl}
  size='tiny'
/>
```

Comment: It is working, but you get the error `Warning: Failed prop type: Prop 'wrapped' in 'Image' conflicts with props: 'href'. They cannot be defined together, choose one or the other.à

Comment: It's a bug, was fixed in `0.73.0`